# How can you get Object.keys() to read the properties of a breeze entity?

Tags: javascript, breeze

I am trying to use Breeze with an Angular application using reactive forms.

The `FormGroup.patchValue()` function takes my breeze entity object and should be able to patch it into my form.

However, `patchValue()` uses `Object.keys()` to iterate over the objects properties to know what values to patch in.

`Object.keys()` does NOT recognize inherited properties.

The typescript objects that breeze tooling generates have the properties assigned using inheritance.

So none of the properties are visible to Object.keys() except for `entityAspect` and `_backingStore` for some reason.

So this makes reactive forms in Angular totally useless with breeze entities.

Is there a way to either avoid using inheritance to assign the breeze properties, or some kind of universal transform function I can use to get Object.keys() to see all the properties on my breeze entity objects?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve it (not familiar with breeze), but I would think you could do:

```
function getKeys(obj) {
    var myKeys = Object.keys(obj);
    var protoKeys = Object.keys(obj.constructor.prototype);
    if (Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) {
        protoKeys = protoKeys.concat(getKeys(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)));
    }
    return [...new Set(myKeys.concat(protoKeys))].filter(c => c !== 'constructor');
}
```

Which, using the transpiled typescript from:

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

class CustomGreeter extends Greeter {
    howdy() {
        return 'howdy';
    }
}

let greeter = new Greeter("world");
```

Will give you the list:

```
["greeting", "howdy", "greet"]
```

```js
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
        ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
        function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var Greeter = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Greeter(message) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    };
    return Greeter;
}());
var CustomGreeter = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(CustomGreeter, _super);
    function CustomGreeter() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    CustomGreeter.prototype.howdy = function () {
        return 'howdy';
    };
    return CustomGreeter;
}(Greeter));

var greeter = new CustomGreeter("world");
function getKeys(obj) {
    var myKeys = Object.keys(obj);
    var protoKeys = Object.keys(obj.constructor.prototype);
    if (Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) {
        protoKeys = protoKeys.concat(getKeys(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)));
    }
    return [...new Set(myKeys.concat(protoKeys))].filter(c => c !== 'constructor');
}

console.log(getKeys(greeter))
```